# MERN Stack: Can ExpressJs route add data from one Model to another Model's array attribute?

Tags: javascript, express, mern

I hope I worded that correctly.  Let me explain.

I'm creating an app where users can organize tournaments for a game (separate).

I'm creating this app with the MERN stack, with Redux as well.

I have numerous routes defined, for CRUD functionality and user authentication for example. My current workflow is to create the backend route, test it with Postman, and once it works I create the Redux reducer/action.

I have two data models.  One is User, and one is Tournament.
Tournament model has a bunch of String type attributes like 'title', and one of it's attributes is 'participants' which is Array type.

I'm trying to write a Post request to a tournament/:id that contains the User.username, and push() that into Tournament.participants array.

I have tried multiple things but my current code looks like

```
router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(tournament => tournament.participants.push(req.body))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
});
```

I am lost and could use help.  Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work I think:

```
router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(tournament => {
      tournament.participants.push(req.body)
      // save the updated tournament to the DB and take advantage of Promise-chaining
      return tournament.save()
    })
    // send a response to the client
    .then(savedTournament => res.json(savedTournament))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
});
```

You just need to make sure you save the updated tournament to the DB with this line:

```
return tournament.save()
```

Then, that will return a Promise which you can chain and then send off a response if successful. You were pulling the Model from the DB and updating the participants array, but then you need to store it in the DB and send a response to the client.

Comment: That worked! I was overthinking this task a lot and its taken me awhile.  Thank you!